# Uncertain MerkleTree Algorithm

Tags: cryptography, merkle-patricia-tries, merkle

I'm building my own MerkleTree algorithm however I found out that the root value generated from my MK algorithm is not the same that I generated from the online generator https://prathamudeshmukh.github.io/merkle-tree-demo/
Any idea? I'm wondering if my MK algorithm is wrong.

```
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value
from turtle import left
from typing import List
import typing
import hashlib


class Node:

    def __init__(self, left, right, value, content):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.content = content
    
    @staticmethod
    def hashNodes(string):
        return hashlib.sha256(string.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()


class MerkleTree:

    def __init__(self, values):

        self.buildTree(values)


    def buildTree(self,leaves):
    
        if len(leaves) % 2 ==1:
           leaves.append(leaves[-1:][0])


        lenArray = len(leaves)
        while lenArray % 2 != 0:
            lenArray.append(lenArray[-1:])
            lenArray = len(leaves)

      
        tempArray = []
        for i in range(0, len(leaves), 2):
            left = Node.hashNodes(leaves[i])
            right = Node.hashNodes(leaves[i+1])
            tempArray.append(Node.hashNodes(left+right))
            
        
        if len(tempArray) == 1:
            self.root = tempArray[0]

        else:
            self.buildTree(tempArray)
    
    def getRoot(self):
        return self.root
            

      

   
        

elems = ["1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7"]
root = MerkleTree(elems)
```

Please advise

Comment: Can you provide the code of your MerkleTree algorithm implementation?

Comment: @JeremyThen - Hi, I just updated my question with the code.

Comment: Do you if you use the same hashing function?

Comment: What do you mean by that? @upavloff

Comment: @David To construct the Merkle Tree you hash some values, do you know if you're using the same hashing function as the website you mention?

Comment: @upavloff- That's a great question. I've no idea about what hashing algorithm the website uses. hm.... However, do you think my MK algorithm makes sense?